# Use Arcgis.com map package as a web map?

Tags: arcgis-online

In Arcmap 10 there is a menu item to create a map package and upload to [Arcgis Online](http://www.arcgis.com/) (*File > Create Map Package > upload to...*). That works fairly smoothly, if a tad slow sometimes. However once placed in system it seems the only way to access the map is to download the map package. What we really want to do is create the map in Arcmap Desktop, upload to Arcgis Online, and then embed that map in a website.

If we take exactly the same data and create the map on the website, upload the feature classes individually, apply styling and symbology using the website tools, share, and so on. The resulting map can be opened in a) Arcgis.com map viewer, b) ArcExplorer, and c) Arcmap Desktop.

In the "[My Content](http://www.arcgis.com/home/content.html)" page a map created from Arcmap Desktop is listed as a "Map Package", and a map created entirely using the website is a "Web Map" (what we want).

Am I missing something or is this really the way it's supposed to work? If so it's a terrific duplication of effort.

Answer (score 3):

I believe they want you to purchase an ArcGIS Online for Organizations subscription for this type of functionality.

Anyone can upload a MapPackage and share it like a simple file (which has it's place for some workflows) but if you want ESRI to host and publish the contents of that package as a service (tiles, feature services), you'll need to get a subscription.

cheers
brian

Comment: ahhh. So it's a "beware the demo" thing. We saw relatively seamless Arcmap to web map process at a recent local user conference. I thought maybe it was one of those "coming in the next upgrade" thing, but was hoping for "you missed clicking this button [here]"... :-) Thanks.

Comment: ...and, it's not even available yet: *"...thank you for your interest in evaluating ArcGIS Online for organizations. A free 30 day trial will become available in Q2 2012. If you'd like to receive an e-mail when it's available, please provide us with the following information.* -- http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/evaluate/index.html

Comment: well, it also depends on the pricing. who knows. here is the best link showing the differences between a free account and a paid subscription: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/features/comparison-table.html

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can upload a layer package and use that directly in agonline

Comment: @brad - i'm pretty sure its the same with Layer Packages, you can share them like files but not have ESRI host them as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Packages uploaded to ArcGIS Online cannot be added to ArcGIS Online web maps. To make map packages available for web mapping applications and clients such as ArcGIS Explorer Online and ArcGIS for iOS, you need to publish your data as map services using ArcGIS Server.