# Map Package not accessible even though it's Public In ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, map-package

I have made my map package public but it still looks for a "sign in" in ArcGIS when I try it in any browser:

https://capeportal.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9db9fc3ad0594fefa72798b71c0ff41e

Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your organization has disabled anonymous access, as such when you provide someone a link to a publicly shared item, you need to remove your org from the URL. I can access your item here:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9db9fc3ad0594fefa72798b71c0ff41e

Note the lack of **capeporal.maps** in the URL.

[See this in the help](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/share-items.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_BBA2B4900AF841C29F77E079C6DD6DA9)

***Share public items when anonymous access is disabled***

> If your organization has disabled anonymous access, only members can
>   access the organization's website. However, you can still share the
>   organization's public items by sharing the item through the public URL
>   (https://www.arcgis.com), instead of your organization's URL (for
>   example, https://yourorg.maps.arcgis.com). Here are some of the ways
>   you can share public items through the public URL....

Answer (score 1):

See question/answers for [Use Arcgis.com map package as a web map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25233/use-arcgis-com-map-package-as-a-web-map).

Basically, a map package requires some form of a subscription, whether it is opened in AGOL or in Desktop. You will need to share services publicly in a map vs a map package to not require a subscription.

> *Anyone can upload a MapPackage and share it like a simple file (which
>   has it's place for some workflows) but if you want ESRI to host and
>   publish the contents of that package as a service (tiles, feature
>   services), you'll need to get a subscription.*

And...

> *Packages uploaded to ArcGIS Online cannot be added to ArcGIS Online web maps. To make map packages available for web mapping applications and clients such as ArcGIS Explorer Online and ArcGIS for iOS, you need to publish your data as map services using ArcGIS Server.*